# writing a binary number in a txt file in matlab

Tags: matlab, binary

I have a binary number and I want to save it on a txt file.my code is :

```
 fid=fopen('RT.txt','w')
fprintf(fid,'%d',00111111100000000000000000000000 );
fclose(fid);
```

But the saved value in file is :
1.111111e+029
I exactly want to save the value as the same as it is in binary format(32bit like the number that I wrote here)
can you help me plssss

Answer (score 4):

`00111111100000000000000000000000` is not a binary number in MATLAB. You can save it as a string `'00111111100000000000000000000000'`, or if you want to convert the binary string to a decimal number, you can use `bin2dec('00111111100000000000000000000000')`. And to convert a decimal number to a binary string (which is still an array of characters), use `dec2bin(33)`.

Comment: Thank you!
I improved your answer now you I can save the value of x on filefprintf(fid,'%s',string(dec2bin(hex2dec(num2hex(single(10))),32)) );

Comment: @ArminBabaei Please accept the answer if you think it was helpful. :) Also I do not see why you are going through the hex conversion. :P